# Apply ContentThemeTransition on a scrollable TextBlock

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, transition, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to create a TextBlock that transitions its content when its value changes (slide in from left).
The problem is that the transition is replayed each time the user scrolls the TextBlock (which is wrapped inside a ScrollViewer)

```
    <ScrollViewer Width="300" Height="200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" >
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}">
            <TextBlock.Transitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <ContentThemeTransition HorizontalOffset="-500" />
                </TransitionCollection>
            </TextBlock.Transitions>
            "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a WinRT bug?

Answer (score 1):

I think I responded to your Connect bug, but can you use EntranceThemeTransition instead here?

Comment: Yes but EntranceThemeTransition plays the animation only once. ContentThemeTransition would intuitively be the right choice, but it behaves incorrectly in Windows 8 Release Preview.